# Doorkeeper client server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, doorkeeper

On railscast epidose "#353 OAuth with Doorkeeper", it has no client application set up. How to set up client application server to avoid the `This webpage is not available` on browser, instead return something.

I've already tried the following found on this [link](http://doorkeeper-sinatra.herokuapp.com/), but it still doesn't work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2016/03/27/omniauth-doorkeeper-devise-redirect-to-the-application-after-signupsignin/

Answer (score 0):

Refer this repository by RyanB.

[353-oauth-with-doorkeeper/oauth_client/](https://github.com/railscasts/353-oauth-with-doorkeeper/tree/1978fab16212be1df2ff8a47e05f821699f963e3/oauth_client)